# What is the meaning of "less a function of" in the following sentence

Tags: idiom-meaning

> Given such a view of thought and rationality, human performance and experience 
>   that take form in nondiscursive modes of conception and expression are 
>   regarded as nonrational, somehow **less a function of** human intelligence 
>   and clearly having little to do with knowing or understanding.

What is the meaning of the bolded part?

Answer (score 4):

When thing-A is said to be "a function of" thing-B (excepting in the mathematical sense) it means that there is a causal link- Thing A is *as a result of* or *derived from* Thing-B

If you substitute the words "not derived from" for "less a function of" then the meaning will remain the same but will hopefully be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your hand off of a burning hot stove, is not a function of human intelligence, it simply hurts and your react instinctively. Cooking a meal on the other hand involves a great many steps that are a function of human intelligence.

The sentence is using big words to categorize and contrast the two types of activity.